# What is Kotlin's way to have similar effect as flags enum variable in C#

Tags: kotlin

In C#, I can do this.

```
[Flags]
enum BeerProperty
{
    Bold = 1,
    Refreshing = 2
}

static void Taste(BeerProperty beer)
{
    if (beer == (BeerProperty.Bold | BeerProperty.Refreshing))
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("I can't qutie put my finger on...");
    }
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var tickBeer = BeerProperty.Bold | BeerProperty.Refreshing;
    Taste(tickBeer);
}
```

In Kotlin, it seems that I cannot "OR" two flags. What is the Kotlin's way to do this? Using a list of enum variables?

```
enum class BeerProperty(value:Int)
{
    Bold(1),
    Refreshing(2)
}

fun taste(beer:BeerProperty)
{
    if(beer == (BeerProperty.Bold | BeerProperty.Refreshing))
    {
        print("I can't qutie put my finger on...");
    }
}

fun main(args: Array<String>)
{
    val tickBeer = BeerProperty.Bold | BeerProperty.Refreshing;
    taste(tickBeer);
}
```

---

Added: Thank you for the answer (which I cannot mark as answer yet, due to time limitation). I modified the code like below and achieved what I wanted.

```
fun taste(beer: EnumSet<BeerProperty>)
{
    if(beer.contains(BeerProperty.Bold) && beer.contains(BeerProperty.Refreshing))
    {
        print("I can't qutie put my finger on...");
    }
}

fun main(args: Array<String>)
{
    val tickBeer = EnumSet.of(BeerProperty.Bold, BeerProperty.Refreshing);
    taste(tickBeer);
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Indeed, in Kotlin every enum constant is an instance of the class corresponding to the enum, and you can't use 'OR' to combine multiple class instances. If you need to track multiple enum values, the most efficient way to do that is to use the [EnumSet class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/EnumSet.html).

Answer (score 20):

## Using extension functions

```
import java.util.*

enum class BeerProperty
{
    BOLD,
    REFRESHING,
    STRONG;

    infix fun and(other: BeerProperty) = BeerProperties.of(this, other)
}

typealias BeerProperties = EnumSet<BeerProperty>

infix fun BeerProperties.allOf(other: BeerProperties) = this.containsAll(other)
infix fun BeerProperties.and(other: BeerProperty) = BeerProperties.of(other, *this.toTypedArray())

fun taste(beer: BeerProperties) {
    if(beer allOf (BeerProperty.BOLD and BeerProperty.REFRESHING and BeerProperty.STRONG)) {
        print("I can't qutie put my finger on...")
    }
}

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val tickBeer = BeerProperty.BOLD and BeerProperty.REFRESHING and BeerProperty.STRONG
    taste(tickBeer)
}
```

I use extension functions to allow properties to be added with and, and allof to check all flags are set.

Comment: This is such a clean, elegant solution! The more I look at Kotlin, the more I love it. +1

Comment: the only problem is when you want to specify just one property, how do you handle that?

Answer (score 3):

You can achieve the same result of c# enum flags in this way

```
enum class TestType(val value: Int)
{
    x(1),
    y(2),
    z(4)
}

fun Int.hasFlag(flag: Int): Boolean
{
    return ((this and flag) == flag)
}
```

Usage:

```
val myType = TestType.x.value or TestType.y.value //myType = 3

println(myType.hasFlag(TestType.x.value)) //true

println(myType.hasFlag(TestType.y.value)) //true

println(myType.hasFlag(TestType.z.value)) //false

println(myType.hasFlag(TestType.x.value or TestType.y.value)) //true

println(myType.hasFlag(TestType.x.value or TestType.z.value)) //false
```

Answer (score 0):

In my way I had simple enum class:

```
enum class Border(val value: Int) {
    None(0),

    Left(1),
    Top(2),
    Right(4),
    Bottom(8),
}
```

Than I created analog of [Flags] enum:

```
class Borders {

    private var value = Border.None.value

    fun add(border: Border) {
        value = value.or(border.value)
    }

    fun has(border: Border) =
        value.and(border.value) == border.value

    fun del(border: Border) {
        value = value.and(border.value.inv())
    }
}
```

And now I can use:

```
class BordersTests {

    @Test
    fun test01() {

        val borders = Borders()
        Assert.assertEquals(borders.has(Border.Top), false)

        borders.add(Border.Top)
        Assert.assertEquals(borders.has(Border.Top), true)

        borders.del(Border.Top)
        Assert.assertEquals(borders.has(Border.Top), false)
    }
}
```